# How this Jquery function calls [jumping window]?

Tags: php, jquery

Go to the site here: http://en.heroes.gpotato.eu/ and click Register. What is the jquery function or plugin to make this jumping window? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the jQueryUI framework, downloadable at the jQuery site - http://jqueryui.com

Then, all you need to do, is create a hidden div on your screen, that will be the dialog. Initialize it as a dialog, and then attach the open dialog event to the click() event of the button you want.

Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#RegisterDialogDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "User Registration",
            buttons: {
                'Close': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Register': function () {
                    RegisterUser();
                }
            }
        });

        $('#RegisterButton').click(function() {
            $('#RegisterDialogDiv').dialog('open');
        });
});
```

For the example to work, you need to have a div with an id of 'RegisterDialogDiv', and a button with an id of 'RegisterButton'.
Of course, don't forget to include the js script files you need, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

If by "jumping" window you mean the modal dialog that pops up, this can be achieved by using the jquery ui dialog plugin.